# Are there cultures in which the decimal separator is longer than one character?

Tags: formatting, number-formatting, cultureinfo, culture

I must write a `stringToNumber` parsing function that can use custom strings for the following:

- decimal separator (`.` for en-US => `3.1415`)
- thousands separator (`,` for en-US => `1,000,000`)
- positive sign (`+` for en-US => `+5`)
- negative sign (`-` for en-US => `-5`)

Can I assume that these are only one character (which would make the implementation easier) or are there any cultures in which any of these are longer?

Comment: By 'one character' are you referring to the '.', ',', '+' and '-'? And are you asking if these are ever repeated more than once in a number format?

Comment: I mean if these can be longer than one character. Like a culture in which you need to specify two dots to indicate the decimal separator. Like this for example: `10..00`

Comment: You seem to be dealing specifically with the en-US culture. I've worked on a number of US, UK, Canadian, South African, etc. based projects and I've never seen any variation where more than one character is used. The only variation I can think of is '-' where in accounting '-5' might be presented as (5).

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to know this as well, and found that I could do this:

```
foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
{
    var sep = ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
    if (sep.Length > 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ci.DisplayName);
        break;
    }
}
```

The results of this is that, no, there is no culture where the NumberDecimalSeparator is greater than 1 character in length. You can also experiment with CurrencyDecimalSeparator and find the same results. I suppose you can check all of them, which I didn't but that's up to you.