# How to determine Thousands Separator using Format in VBA

Tags: vba

I would like to determine the Thousand Separator used while running a VBA Code on a target machine **without** resolving to calling system built-in functions such as (Separator = Application.ThousandsSeparator).

I am using the following simple code using 'Format':

```
ThousandSeparator = Mid(Format(1000, "#,#"), 2, 1)
```

The above seems to work fine, and **would like to confirm if this is a safe method of doing it without resorting to system calls**.

I would expect the result to be a single char string in the form of , or .  or ' or a Space as applicable to the locale on the machine.

Please note that I want to only use a language statement such as Format or similar (no sys calls). Also this relates to Thousands Separator not Decimal Separator. This article [Using VBA to detect which decimal sign the computer is using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652409/using-vba-to-detect-which-decimal-sign-the-computer-is-using) does not help or answer my question. Thanks

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"without resolving to calling system built-in functions"* -  why, when they are available?

Comment: I would like to make the code "OS independent" as much as possible thus reduce conversion time to other OS. Thanks

Comment: I imagine any method used would make a Win API call to get the region settings. You can test by changing the windows region settings

Comment: `Application.ThousandsSeparator` etc. does not give you neccessarily the regional thousand separator, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.decimalseparator).

Comment: @Slai True. But I would rather let the compiler/interpreter do the internal calls and I maintain use of the high-level language statement. Yes I tested it on Windows 10 with various regions and its seems all fine on Windows.

Comment: But using `Application.ThousandsSeparator` **is** the OS independent way of doing this. (Or did you find an OS where that is not available or has the wrong value?)

Comment: @Tomalak: Look at the documentation of [Application.UseSystemSeparators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.usesystemseparators)

Comment: `I would like to make the code "OS independent"` - `Application.ThousandsSeparator` *is* OS independent. It belongs to the *Excel* object model.

Comment: The only difference to the duplicate question is that you want to use `ThousandsSeparator` and `xlThousandsSeparator` instead of the `DecimalSeparator` and `xlDecimalSeparator` respectively.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks. The article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652409/using-vba-to-detect-which-decimal-sign-the-computer-is-using does not address using the Format function for Thousands separator.

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei You should not be using it for that, but I guess you can. `Format` will use the system separator (as opposed to `Application.ThousandsSeparator`) if that is what you are asking about, but it feels like kind of a hack. Make sure that `UseSystemSeparators` is `True` and use `Application.International(xlThousandsSeparator)`.

Comment: @GSerg Even when Application.UseSystemSeparators = False the Format function still gives the correct output. Why then use extra application calls and setting them to false and true if a simple Format statement would give the correct result irrespective.

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei You may be right. By the way, using `Format` [is addressed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53205733/11683)  in the question (although while a single unescaped dot does result in the decimal separator being printed, a single thousands separator does not, and requires some number positions around it like you are doing). And there is yet another way with the registry, but now that *is* OS-dependent.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for your feedback. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strict answer to whether it is safe to use `Format` to get the thousands separator is **No**.

E.g. on Windows, it is possible to enter up to three characters into the Thousands Separator field in the regional settings in the control panel.
Suppose you enter `asd` and click OK.

If you now call `Format(1000, "#,#")` it will give you `1a000`. That is only the first letter of your thousands separator. You have failed to retrieve it correctly.

[Reading the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53205733/11683):

```vb
? CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKCU\Control Panel\International\sThousand")
```

you get back `asd` in full.

To be fair, the Excel international properties do not seem to be of much help either. `Application.International(xlThousandsSeparator)` in this situation will return the separator originally defined in your computer's locale, not the value you've overridden it to.

Having that said, the practical answer is Yes, because it would appear (and if you happen to know for sure, please post an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46538917/11683)) that there is no culture with multi-char thousand separator (even in China where scary things like [`1億2345万6789` or `1億2345萬6789`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Other_numeral_systems) exist, they happen to be represented with [just one UTF-16 character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14115503/11683)), and you probably are happy to ignore the people who decided to play with their locale settings in that fashion.